# How does Dream Weaver CS5 save the code collapse state?

Tags: dreamweaver

When Collapsing a code in Dreamweaver CS5, the collapse state is saved as long as the file is in the same folder, however when copying the file to a new folder the collapse state vanishes and the code expands, So does anybody know how to keep the code collapsed even after copying it or uploading it to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

if you are referring to this feature, then this is set in dreamweaver and not within the file, so when you move the file, dreamweaver will see it as a different files like so:

```
root/index.php
```

and moved to another location

```
root/another_folder/index.php
```

so this would have to be reset everytime you move it.

hope this helps